# Incrementing Left padding a string

Tags: java, padding

I have the String = 82868184847, and I want to left pad it with numbers starting from 000 to 999. I tried doing this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        number = String.format("%02d", i);
        paddedNum = number;
   }
```

I want my output to be
      00082868184847
      00182868184847
      00282868184847
      ...
      99982868184847

but I get
     00082868184847
01082868184847
02082868184847
....

Comment: Use `%03d` to get a 3 digit number.

Comment: I did but I still get 000082868184847, 001082868184847, 002082868184847.....

Comment: How are you getting and printing those numbers?

Comment: Now you just need to remove that extra `0` that's separating the two numbers. Could you show the code which formats the other part of the number?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++) {

   salt = String.format("%03d", i);
   saltedPassword = salt + unsaltedPassword;            
   System.out.print(" " + saltedPassword + " ");

Comment: how do I remove that extra 0?

Comment: Somehow `unsaltedPassword` is being `0` padded before that calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String key = "82868184847";String salt ;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++) {
            salt = String.format("%03d", i);
            System.out.println( salt + key);}`